# Restrict direct IP access to site - SSL

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, vps

I have a CentOS 6 VPS with 5 sites and Let's Encrypt installed and working on all sites. When I access https://vps-ip, it always points to the first site configured in vhosts-ssl-letsencrypt.conf (I've changed the config and put another site at the top of the config to test it).
I've tried to add:

```
<VirtualHost ip:443>
    ServerName ip
    Redirect 403 /
    ErrorDocument 403 "No"
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs
    UseCanonicalName Off
    UserDir disabled
</VirtualHost>
```

but sites are not accessible via ssl

```
or <VirtualHost *:443>...
```

gives me this error: [error] Server should be SSL-aware but has no certificate configured [Hint: SSLCertificateFile] ((null):0)

```
<VirtualHost *>...
```

no change

http://vps-ip is pointing to the right vps welcome page.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you have not enabled SSL for your `*:443` vhost in the question above. Apache doesn't suddenly start talking SSL for a vhost just because you put it on port 443, it needs configuring.

Also this directive is not one that will do anything sensible:

```
 Redirect 403 /
```

And you should not use

```
<VirtualHost *>
```

That will cause all sorts of problems. Use `IP:port` or `*:port` and nothing else. Also do not mix these two types of arguments unless you know exactly what you are doing.

EDIT: In response to the first comment: Add a `default` SSL virtual host. It must be the first one listed for port 443 in the output of `apachectl -S` and add the IP address as the `ServerName` or a `ServerAlias`

EDIT2: In response to further comments. It would seem you have not enabled SSL. There are an absolute minimum of three SSL directives you need in your virtual host to enable SSL, they are detailed here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/ssl/ssl_howto.html

Comment: SSL is enabled, working both on https://domain.tld and https://ip which points to the first site in my vhosts-ssl-letsencrypt.conf. I want the ip to point to the VPS welcome page not a domain.

Comment: Add the output of `apachectl -S` to your post. I've also added a possible solution to my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply:

>apachectl -S
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using vpsxxx.ovh.net for ServerName
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          vpsxxx.ovh.net (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
Syntax OK

Comment: I have this in ssl.conf:
Listen 443
SSLProtocol ....
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCipherSuite .....

NameVirtualHost ip:443